# Is this done using NSCalendar

Tags: ios, nscalendar

I have been looking at how the mini-calander date is displayed. Is it done with `NSCalendar` or using open source projects?

I can't seem to find out how to do it. If anyone knows how its done or a tutorial about it that would be great. When the date is clicked it opens out a `UIDatePicker`. I expect it must be done using `NSCalendar` but cannot see anything about it.

[image: Screenshot of Calendar Date]

Comment: It's just an icon created by the app based on the current date.

Comment: Do you mean creating the icon or displaying the `UIDatePicker`?

Comment: icon display....I have everything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you would use NSDate.

Get the current day and month, then create labels the size of the icon, center the text and add them to the subview of the icon. I'm on my phone at the moment so I can't give a large description. But that would be the way I would do it.

**EDIT**

To answer your comment of adding a UILabel to the titleview of the navigationbar (navigationItem), I have added a UISlider to the navigationItem.titleView:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(50, 150, 220, 23);
slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[slider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
slider.continuous = YES; // Make the slider 'stick' as it is moved.
[slider setMinimumValue:0];
[slider setMaximumValue:((float)[numbers count] - 1)];
//slider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * - 0.5);
self.navigationItem.titleView = slider;
```

You can do the exact same with adding a UIView(1) that contains several other UIViews(2) with Labels inside those UIViews(2), just like how the image posted earlier has done... Then add a control event or gesture recognizer to the UIView(2) that allows some type of action to occur...

Honestly, I have come to realize, almost ANYTHING is possible in app development. It just matters how your approach your problem and if your up for the challenge...

If your still having issues, send a comment and I'll do exactly what your trying to do, but it is a good learning experience doing it yourself... But i'm here to help :)

Comment: you cant add a uilabel to the navigation bar though?

Comment: you can but your going to have to create a custom titleview which was most likely dont... Custom titleview meaning a UIView that is the titleview of the navigationbar. Ill give you some code in a bit